# Rendered Image and preview look different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

I am new to blender and I have been trying to get a render in Cycles. But the image looks nothing alike. There's a reflection the object which isn't there in the preview

Preview:
[image]

Final Render:

[image]

I used a ocean modifier here

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to get the exact thing?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot of your Ocean modifier you have Resolution Viewport set to 20 but Resolution Render, just below, set to 2. The Resolution settings determine how many levels of subdivision are present in the final result.

In ‘preview’ mode the resolution of 20 is giving enough detail to be able to see the ripples but in Render mode you’re effectively just seeing a flat surface.

Increase the Render resolution to match the Viewport resolution.

Comment: DAMNNNNN!, It worked. Thanks a lot good sir and have a happy new year